# Typescript error using ref.current from component which forwards ref to a RN component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

New TypeScript user. I am converting a RN project to TypeScript. Using hooks all around. I've defined a component BitInput (which forwards a ref to TextInput) as follows:

```
export interface Props {
  value: number;
  onChange?: (newValue: number) => void;
}

const BitInput: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef(
  ({ value, onChange }, ref: React.Ref<TextInput>) => {
    return (
      <TextInput
        ref={ref}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    );
};
```

I'm using this component to build a ByteInput component as follows:

```
import BitInput from './BitInput';

const BinaryInput: React.FC<Props> = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const ref: React.MutableRefObject<typeof BitInput | undefined>[] = [...Array(8)].map(() => useRef<typeof BitInput>() );

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'ArrowRight':
        for (let i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
          if (ref[i].current?.isFocused() && i < ref.length - 1) {
            ref[i + 1].current.focus();
            break;
          }
        }
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <BitInput
          ref={ref[refIndex++]}
          onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
          />
      </View>
      ..... 7 more BitInputs here .....
    );
  }
```

I am getting `TS2339: Property 'isFocused' does not exist on type 'FC '.`

I'm also getting:

```
 TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<FC<Props>>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<TextInput>'.
   Type 'MutableRefObject<FC<Props>>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<TextInput>'.
     Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
       Type 'FunctionComponent<Props>' is missing the following properties from type 'TextInput': isFocused, clear, measure, measureInWindow, and 19 more.
  BitInput.tsx(11, 3): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

I can fix both, by using `BitInput` instead of `typeof BitInput` in the ref declaration. But now I'm getting `TS2749: 'BitInput' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here` on it, and on the JSX for BitCode I got the TS error that a lot of the required props are missing.

I'm guessing I'm not specifying the export interface correctly, but what is the proper way?

Comment: I'd like to know what the solution here is.